# TCPDF unable to read Yesteryear font

Tags: php, fonts, tcpdf

TCPDF unable to read the yesteryear font, but it works for Arial and calibri which I installed the same way as I did for yesteryear.

```html
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?--><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="1200" height="600" style="background-color: transparent" viewBox="0 0 1200 600" xml:space="preserve"><desc>Created with Fabric.js 1.6.3</desc><defs> <style type="text/css">@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yesteryear);@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arial);@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){return h});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function Array() {    [native code]});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b,a){Array.forEach(this,b,a);return this});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){for(var b=this.length,a=Array(b);b--;)a[b]=q(this[b]);return a});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){return this.filter(function(b){return null!=b})});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b){var a=Array.slice(arguments,1);return this.map(function(c){return c[b].apply(c,a)})});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b){for(var a={},c=Math.min(this.length,b.length),d=0;d&lt;c;d++)a[b[d]]=this[d];return a});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b){for(var a={},c=0,d=this.length;c&lt;d;c++)for(var e in b)if(b[e](this[c])){a[e]=this[c];delete b[e];break}return a});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b,a){return-1!=this.indexOf(b,a)});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b){this.push.apply(this,b);return this});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){return this.length?this[this.length-1]:null});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){return this.length?this[Number.random(0,this.length-1)]:null});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b){this.contains(b)||this.push(b);return this});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b){for(var a=0,c=b.length;a&lt;c;a++)this.include(b[a]);return this});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b){for(var a=this.length;a--;)this[a]===b&amp;&amp;this.splice(a,1);return this});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){this.length=0;return this});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){for(var b=[],a=0,c=this.length;a&lt;c;a++){var d=typeOf(this[a]);"null"!=d&amp;&amp;(b=b.concat("array"==d||"collection"==d||"arguments"==d||instanceOf(this[a],Array)?Array.flatten(this[a]):this[a]))}return b});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){for(var b=0,a=this.length;b&lt;a;b++)if(null!=this[b])return this[b];return null});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b){if(3!=this.length)return null;var a=this.map(function(b){1==b.length&amp;&amp;(b+=b);return b.toInt(16)});return b?a:"rgb("+a+")"});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(b){if(3&gt;this.length)return null;if(4==this.length&amp;&amp;0==this[3]&amp;&amp;!b)return"transparent";for(var a=[],c=0;3&gt;c;c++){var d=(this[c]-0).toString(16);a.push(1==d.length?"0"+d:d)}return b?a:"#"+a.join("")});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){return Math.min.apply(null,this);});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){return Math.max.apply(null,this);});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){return this.length?this.sum()/this.length:0;});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){var b=0,c=this.length;if(c){while(c--){b+=this[c];}}return b;});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){return[].combine(this);});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){for(var c=this.length;c&amp;&amp;--c;){var b=this[c],d=Math.floor(Math.random()*(c+1));this[c]=this[d];this[d]=b;}return this;});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){var c=this[0],d=this[1],k=this[2],h=0;var j=Math.max(c,d,k),f=Math.min(c,d,k);var l=j-f;var i=j/255,g=(j!=0)?l/j:0;if(g!=0){var e=(j-c)/l;var b=(j-d)/l;var m=(j-k)/l;if(c==j){h=m-b;}else{if(d==j){h=2+e-m;}else{h=4+b-e;}}h/=6;if(h&lt;0){h++;}}return[Math.round(h*360),Math.round(g*100),Math.round(i*100)];});@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=function(){var d=Math.round(this[2]/100*255);if(this[1]==0){return[d,d,d];}else{var b=this[0]%360;var g=b%60;var h=Math.round((this[2]*(100-this[1]))/10000*255);var e=Math.round((this[2]*(6000-this[1]*g))/600000*255);var c=Math.round((this[2]*(6000-this[1]*(60-g)))/600000*255);switch(Math.floor(b/60)){case 0:return[d,c,h];case 1:return[e,d,h];case 2:return[h,d,c];case 3:return[h,e,d];case 4:return[c,h,d];case 5:return[d,h,e];}}return false;});</style></defs><g transform="translate(600 300)"><image id="1515749497617" xlink:href="https://www.printyourproduct.online/images/virtuemart/product/1448628762_5.png" x="-250" y="-250" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: none; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" width="500" height="500" preserveAspectRatio="none"></image></g> <g id="1515749497805" transform="translate(600 300)">  <text font-family="Yesteryear" font-size="28.01" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">   <tspan x="-196.13" y="8.82" fill="#000000">Καμβάς ορθογώνιος χωρίς τελάρο </tspan>  </text> </g> <g id="1515749497861" transform="translate(593 202)">  <text font-family="Arial" font-size="18" font-style="normal" font-weight="normal" text-decoration="normal" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: rgb(0,0,0); fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;">   <tspan x="-136.69" y="5.67" fill="#000000">Καμβάς ορθογώνιος χωρίς τελάρο</tspan>  </text> </g></svg>
```

[Yesteryear font downloaded from here](https://github.com/google/fonts/blob/master/ofl/yesteryear/Yesteryear-Regular.ttf)

```
$fontname = TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont('data/Yesteryear-Regular.ttf', 'TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 18);
$pdf->ImageSVG($file='images/firstview.svg', $x=0, $y=5, $w='', $h='', $link='', $align='', $palign='', $border=0, $fitonpage=false);
```

But I did not get the correct output:
[image: Wrong output]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Ok, thankyou for telling this.